# How to add ::before pseudo element on elements created dynamically by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating some elements dynamically with jquery. (say with id `test_element1`, `test_element2` and so on..)

I have the below CSS -

```
div[id^=test_]:before  {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: #aaaaaa 0px 0px 10px inset;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The `::before` element does not show up when I inspect the element. It shows up only if the `test_element1` is already present in my HTML (ie. static content).

How do I make the `::before` appear for my dynamic elements ?

Comment: A runnable snippet would be nice, please.

Comment: Do you have `position:relative` on the `div`? - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxjjjdh/1/)?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/vamid/1/watch?css,js,output It seems fine to me.

Comment: Thanks Hashim, you are right. My div was in an iframe, hence the issue.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example. Can you put your code into a JS fiddle so we can inspect your code?

Answer (score 0):

There really should be no reason for the pseudo element not showing up. Maybe check your code to see if there is a problem elsewhere. Here is a working example of what you are trying to achieve, maybe you can compare this with your code and find a solution for your specific case. But the ultimate answer is that it should be working, so the problem is not the css/jquery relationship.

```js
$("body").append(

  $("<div />", {
    "id": "test_element1"
  }).html("test"),

  $("<div />", {
    "id": "test_element2"
  }).html("test"),

  $("<div />", {
    "id": "test_element3"
  }).html("test")

);
```

```css
div[id^=test_] {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

div[id^=test_]::before {
  content: "i am pseudo element";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: #aaaaaa 0px 0px 10px inset;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div[id^=test_] {
    position: relative;
}
div[id^=test_]:before  {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: #aaaaaa 0px 0px 10px inset;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

This will be the solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(count < 5){
      let btn = document.createElement('button');
      let len = document.querySelectorAll('button').length;
      btn.classList.add('text_'+ parseInt(len + 1));
      btn.innerText = 'Button ' + parseInt(len + 1);
      document.body.appendChild(btn);
      count+=1;
    }else{
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
 }, 5000)
```

```css
button{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  color:#fff;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius:5px;
}
button[class^="text_"]:before{
  content: 'Before';
  position:absolute;
  left: 100%;
  height:30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<button class="text_1">Button 1</button>
```

Please check this code snippet and fix your code accordingly. Here I am generating dynamic button with dynamic id. I have also specified css property using pseudo attribute selector.

Edit your code and let me know your thoughts. I hope this will fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

the answer is that

You can not manipulate the pseudo elements like :after and :before using javascript or jquery. You cannot even add then dynamically.

Comment: While true, it doesn't answer the question. It is an answer to another question.

Comment: The OP is not trying to add pseudo elements in JS. He’s adding the element itself. The CSS handles the pseudos.

Answer (score -1):

**When you set pseudo element, selector z-index + position need to added.**

```css
div[id^=test_]  {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
div[id^=test_]:before  {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: #aaaaaa 0px 0px 10px inset;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```